# Can I make yum only install the versions of packages that would have come from a particular CentOS release's media?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I'm trying to create a Docker image that mimics the environment from an old CentOS release (e.g. CentOS 6.3), as it would have been installed from the installation media only (with no updates); the system that I'm trying to duplicate isn't network-connected. Essentially, I would like to start with a minimal install, then add the additional packages that I need to match the target configuration.

I currently have a `Dockerfile` that does this by using `yum install` commands. However, this tends to download the latest versions of all of the packages and their dependencies instead. Can I force `yum` to only install RPMs from the repository that matches what was on the original install media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter a lot by enabling/disabling certain repositories in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.

You can also download iso image of your desired distro release, mount it `somewhere` using

```
sudo mount -o loop release.iso somewhere
```

and create own repository using `createrepo` (nice howto is available at https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalRepos) and point your dnf/yum to that repository only.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a pretty good solution. I also achieved what I wanted by editing `yum`'s config to disable all of the repos except for the CentOS 6.4 vault repository.

Comment: This way (of course not mounting the ISO but extracting it to the disc) you can manage updates or you can add custom packages to your repo too.